# Replicate Multiple Database to Single Database AND conversely

Tags: mysql, replication

Here is my Master-Master Replication Scenario

```
-------------------
| Master/Slave 1  |
| Database = MainDB |
-------------------
/\
|
|
|
\/
-------------------
| Master/Slave 2  |
| Database = DB1  |
| Database = DB2  |
| Database = DB3  |
-------------------
```

Here is my Master/Slave1 Configure:

```
[mysqld]
binlog_format                   = MIXED
user                            = mysql
port                            = 3306
socket                          = /tmp/mysql.sock
#bind-address                    = 127.0.0.1
basedir                         = /usr/local
datadir                         = /var/db/mysql
tmpdir                          = /var/db/mysql_tmpdir
slave-load-tmpdir               = /var/db/mysql_tmpdir
secure-file-priv                = /var/db/mysql_secure
log-bin                         = MainDB.log
replicate-do-db                 = MainDB
replicate-rewrite-db            = "DB1->MainDB"
replicate-rewrite-db            = "DB2->MainDB"
replicate-rewrite-db            = "DB3->MainDB"
replicate-rewrite-db            = "DB4->MainDB"
log-output                      = TABLE
master-info-repository          = TABLE
relay-log-info-repository       = TABLE
relay-log-recovery              = 1
slow-query-log                  = 1
server-id                       = 1
```

and my Master/Slave2 Configure:

```
[mysqld]
binlog_format                   = mixed
user                            = mysql
port                            = 3306
socket                          = /tmp/mysql.sock
#bind-address                    = 127.0.0.1
basedir                         = /usr/local
datadir                         = /var/db/mysql
tmpdir                          = /var/db/mysql_tmpdir
slave-load-tmpdir               = /var/db/mysql_tmpdir
secure-file-priv                = /var/db/mysql_secure
log-bin                         = mysql-bin
log-output                      = TABLE
master-info-repository          = TABLE
relay-log-info-repository       = TABLE
relay-log-recovery              = 1
slow-query-log                  = 1
server-id                       = 2
log_bin                         = cloud.log
binlog-do-db                    = DB1
binlog-do-db                    = DB2
binlog-do-db                    = DB3
binlog-do-db                    = DB4
```

With this configuration I can replicate from Master/slave2 to Master/slave1 but it can't replicate conversely. 
How cloud change my.cnf for both to be replicated together?

Comment: Can you specify how you want Master/slave2 to handle the MainDB coming from Master/slave2.. I mean for example do you want some tables go to this DB1 and some goes to DB2...?

Answer (score 0):

> (1)If a master server does not write a statement to its binary log,
>   the statement is not replicated. If the server does log the statement,
>   the statement is sent to all slaves and each slave determines whether
>   to execute it or ignore it.

**Master/Slave1** receive a binlog that has all **DB%** from **Master/Slave2** so he can handle to rewrite every DB into the **MainDB**. (using this `replicate-rewrite-db` even this option is a bit dangerous for me and you have to be carrful otherwise it will break see this [option_mysqld_replicate-rewrite-db](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-rewrite-db) ).

First, In master master I think you should enable the option of loging in the slave `log_slave_updates` so the other slave "master" can store the statement in binary log (1). check this as well to undertand [how Servers Evaluate Replication Filtering Rules](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-rules.html)

In the other hand **Master/Slave2** receive a binglog that has one database **MainDB**, and there is nothing you wrote than can help on taking a part to another Database. or rewrite everything in one.

> On the master, you can control which databases to log changes for by
>   using the `--binlog-do-db` and `--binlog-ignore-db` options to control
>   binary logging.

So you have to add this option in the **Master/Slave1** to tell him to log the changes of **MainDB**, then in **Master/Slave2** you specify which database you want to rewrite on it or which tables you want to  replicate in which database

Answer (score 0):

yes we know it should be replicated with some DB in master/slave2 but we want to get back to that specific DB which had replicated to MainDB.